How to create a seaborn heatmap that is not a spectrum, but 4 distinct colors
I have the following code which is working well, but as all correlations in the heatmap are whole numbers, I would like the legend on the right to not be a spectrum, but just to have 4 distinct colors, matching that of the heat map.

I tried to do it with this below, but it did not work
# Specify colors for numbers 0-4
cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r.reversed()  # Choose a colormap for numbers greater than 4
cmap_colors = [cmap(i) for i in range(5)]  # Get colors for 0-4

One other aspect I have been trying to figure out, is why there is not a black boarder the entire way around, as it is missing on the bottom and right side, even though I have line color set to black.
Any suggestions with either of these would be appreciated!
Full Code
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("UA_CSV_v2.csv", delimiter=';')

# Set up the X-axis labels
x_axis_labels = [
    'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6', 'M7', 'M8',
    'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8',
    'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5',
    'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4',
    'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 
]

# Set up the Y-axis labels
y_axis = ['Robustness', 'Self-Sufficency', 'Polycentric Governance',
          'Social Cohesion', 'Learning and Innovation', 'Social-Ecological Justice']

# Create a subset DataFrame containing only the relevant columns for the heatmap
subset_df = df[y_axis]

# Transpose the subset DataFrame so that the rows become the columns
subset_df = subset_df.transpose()

# Plot the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))  # Increased height to accommodate y-axis labels

# Specify colors for numbers 0-4
cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r.reversed()  # Choose a colormap for numbers greater than 4
cmap_colors = [cmap(i) for i in range(5)]  # Get colors for 0-4

# Plot the heatmap with specified colors
heatmap = sns.heatmap(subset_df, annot=True, cmap=cmap, linecolor='black', linewidths=0.8,
                      cbar_kws={'ticks': range(5), 'label': 'Values'}, fmt='g')

# Set the x-axis ticks and labels to the center of each cell
heatmap.set_xticks([tick + 0.5 for tick in range(len(x_axis_labels))])
heatmap.set_xticklabels(x_axis_labels, rotation=90, ha='center')

# Set the font size and weight of the title and axis labels
plt.title("Impact of UA on General Urban Resilience Capacities", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', y=1.02)
plt.xlabel("Urban Agriculture Indicators", fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel("Resilience Capacities", fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')

# Set custom colors for each section of the Y-axis
for i, label in enumerate(heatmap.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if label.get_text().startswith('M'):
        label.set_color('red')
    elif label.get_text().startswith('S'):
        label.set_color('green')
    elif label.get_text().startswith('E'):
        label.set_color('blue')
    elif label.get_text().startswith('I'):
        label.set_color('orange')
    elif label.get_text().startswith('G'):
        label.set_color('purple')

# Increase the font size of the tick labels for both x and y axes
heatmap.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)

# Adjust the layout to ensure y-axis labels are fully visible
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)  # Increase the left margin

# Remove grid lines
plt.grid(False)

# Create a custom discrete legend
colorbar = heatmap.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks(range(5))  # Set ticks for legend
colorbar.set_ticklabels(range(5))  # Set tick labels for legend

# Save the plot to an image file with appropriate size for Word
plt.savefig("heatmap2.png", dpi=300)  # Adjust the file name and DPI as needed

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


To re-enable the frame: for spine in heatmap.spines.values(): spine.set_visible(True).  You can also add sns.heatmap(..., clip_on=False) to avoid the outer lines being clipped.
